# PHP & MySQL One item in multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql, database

I try to select all the items from `stores` table that can belong to multiple categories

This is my table structure:

`stores` table

```
id
name
```

`categories` table

```
id
name
```

`store_category` table

```
store_id
category_id
```

I've tried the folowing query but it doesn't work as i wanted:

```
SELECT * FROM (stores JOIN store_category ON stores.id = store_category.store_id) JOIN categories ON store_category.category_id = categories.id
```

What i want to do is like:

> Select all  `stores` that have category_id = php var $category_id set in `store_category`

*added as pseudocode

How can i do this?

PS: example of populated tables

```
`stores`

id  |  name
1   |  amazon
1   |  aliexpress


`categories`

id  | name
1   | smartphones
2   | fashion

`store_category`

store_id  |  category_id
1         |  1
1         |  2
2         |  1
2         |  2
```

From this table design i want to express that both stores are included in the two categories

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want?

Comment: I want to display all the stores from one category

Comment: group by http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/04/do-you-really-understand-sqls-group-by-and-having-clauses/

Comment: Do you have any kind of php script at all? E.g. setting up a database connection and issuing some kind of sql query. Or do you want a complete script?

Comment: I have thr script & database connection. I just can't select the query based on that condition.

Comment: Could you describe the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all the stores that belong to the category with name 'some_category' then you can try this:

```
SELECT aa.id, aa.name
FROM stores AS aa
INNER JOIN store_category AS bb
ON aa.id = bb.store_id
INNER JOIN category AS cc
ON bb.category_id = cc.id
WHERE cc.name = 'some_category';
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In this Sample i get first all row with the category name and then i join the stores. So you not must query all stores with there categories

```
SELECT s.name
FROM store_category AS sc
LEFT JOIN stores AS s ON sc.store_id = c.id
WHERE sc.category_id = 2;
```

It not testet. please let me now if it works for you.

Comment: it doesn't work. Let me explain again: I want to select id & name from `stores` where category_id from `store_category` = $category_id php variable also asigned to store_id

Comment: please see my updated question with example of table design

Comment: i have edit my anwser. so it easy to get all stores where have a category. in my sample i use cat_id 2

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply do this:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.* from table1, table2, table3
   where table1.id=table2.id and table2.id=table3.id and 
   table3.id=table1.id;
```